What is the product of the solutions to the equation (√10)(x^(log (x))) = x^2?
I have spent a few hours on this question but I can't seem to grasp it. I have found that taking the log of both sides doesn't give me any progress. The log exponent identity didn't work. I also tried moving both terms to one side and possible using vieta's but nothing worked. Lastly, I tried squaring both sides, but I don't think that brings me anywhere. Does the radical turning into 10^(1/2) have to do with anything. Can I have a few hints and could someone help me solve this equation. Thanks. I have found this question from a qualifying test that my middle school has for ARML.

Just out of curiosity, when you say "taking log of both sides", exactly what did you get as a result of that before you gave up? What obstructed the log exponent identity from working?

Can you please format your expressions using MathJax. It's hard to read otherwise.

When I took the log of both sides of (√10)(log(x))(log(x))=2*log(x), I divided both sides by log(x) and kept account for division by 0, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't remove any solutions to get the equation (√10)(log(x)=2. Then proceeded to get (log(x)=(√10)/5, but after finding the solutions, the product doesn't match up with the  answer.

Sorry for the format. I tried using MathJax, but for some reason, my laptop wouldn't copy anything, and I am getting tight on studying time to look into this.

write $x = 10^t$   and see what happens. I'm guessing the log is base 10

Yes it is base 10. When I did that and matched exponents, I got t^t+1/2=2t. But, I am unsure how to proceed.

No. $  \left( 10^t \right)^t  = 10^{t^2}  $  In general $  \left( a^b \right)^c  = a^{bc}  $

Yes thank you! I am not sure what my brain was thinking; ignoring this simple of an identity.

COMMENT.-$$\sqrt{10}x^{\log(x)}=x^2\iff x^{\frac{\log(\sqrt{10})}{\log(x)}}\cdot x^{\log(x)}=x^2$$ equating exponents we get
$$\frac{\log(\sqrt{10})}{\log(x)}+\log(x)=2$$ so the quadratic equation
$$X^2-2X+\log(10)=0$$ where $X=\log(x)$. The two solutions are $\log(x)=\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt2}{2}\Rightarrow x=10^{(\frac{-2\pm\sqrt2}{2})}$

I don't think that complies with log identities. I know this for sure because vieta's doesn't give the right answer. Thanks though.

@shivankchintalpati  Piquito is correct. See my comment of one minute ago

But the thing is that when multiplying these solutions, you get 1/100 which is not the answer.

Oh did Piquito mean log(x)=(2+-sqrt(2))/2? In that case, it is right. Thanks.

@shivank chintalpati: your $\dfrac{1}{100}$ is correct because the asked product is $10^{-2}$ (the $\sqrt2$ disappears making the product of two roots).

Sorry, but the answer is 100. @WillJagy was right about his above comment and making x=10^t, which makes log(x) what I have said above. Then adding that means 4/2=2 so 10^2=100, but thanks.

The equation is $X^2-2X+\log(\sqrt{10})=0$, not $X^2-2X+\log(10)=0$. And the solutions are $X=\frac{\color{red}+2\pm\sqrt2}2$. And why does this answer begin with "Comment"?
